# Открытие activity в bottomnavigationview

Tags: android, android-studio, activity, bottom-navigation-view

У меня есть BottomNavigationView с 4 компонентами меню.

Как мне при нажатии на один из компонентов запустить activity? Не фрагменты, а именно activity.

[image: bottomnavigationview]

Answer (score 1):

Нужно для вашего BottomNavigationView определить слушателя нажатий на пункты навигации, где для каждого из пунктов опишите нужные вам вызовы требуемых активити:

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
   new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
         switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.first:
               startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, AwesomeActivity1.class));
               break;
            case R.id.second:
               startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, AwesomeActivity2.class));
               break;
         }
         return true;
      }
});
```

Comment: @anton сделал как вы посоветовали, но при нажатии на нужный мне элемент, открывается MainActivity, а должна открываться ScannerActivity. Вот код: case R.id.navigation_scanner:
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScannerActivity.class));
                    return true;

Comment: @TILL, почему именно у вас открывается не та активити - это уже другой вопрос. И, соответственно, желательно полностью весь код метода, откуда осуществляется старт активити